# Show children of top level category only

Tags: wordpress, categories

Imagine i have a URL structure like this: www.domain.com/category/subcategory/

This is my code:

```
<?php
$args=array(
    'child_of' => $cat-id,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$categories=get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a>';  } 
?>
```

When I'm on "www.domain.com/category/" the code correctly displays all children of the category, but when on "www.domain.com/category/subcategory/" the code doesn't display any results because the subcategory doesnt have any children. I need the code to only display the children of the top-level category even when on it's child pages.

How do i accomplish this? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ancestors = get_ancestors($cat-id, 'category');
$args=array(
    'child_of' => ($ancestors ? end($ancestors) : $cat-id), //If category has ancestors, use the top-most ancestor, otherwise, use the current category ID
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$categories=get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a>';  }
```